# How to create multiple provider network with multiple NIC port in Openstack

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, openstack, nic, openvswitch

how to setup multiple provider network in openstack packstack. I'm deploying on single server with 4 port nic physical. The setup as below

```
port1 (eth0) = provider1 = 192.168.10.0/24
port2 (eth1) = provider2 = 192.168.20.0/24
port3 (eth2) = provider3 = 192.168.30.0/24
port4 (eth3) = provider4 = 192.168.40.0/24
```

As what I understand 1st I need to create ovs bridge and add map to each port. Got others steps such as L3 agent configuration, ML2 plugin and ovs agent which not really clear how to do about it. As I deploying using packstack and got packstack answerfile that can be customized. I have done with single interface port in packstack file but when need to add multiple nic port, I'm not sure which part should I add/change.

If someone had done this using packstack answer file please share how it can be done. Thank you for all you support and help.

***If openstack already deployed can it be changed to fulfill the requirement above? or clean deployment?***

This is parameters answer file which I'm not sure if this is valid as per my requirement. I may wrong and need advise and confirmation below.

```
CONFIG_NEUTRON_L3_EXT_BRIDGE=provider
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TYPE_DRIVERS=vlan,flat
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_FLAT_NETWORKS=*
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=physnet0:br-eth0,physnet1:br-eth1,physnet2:br-eth2,physnet3:br-eth3
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-eth0:eth0,br-eth1:eth1,br-eth2:eth2,br-eth3:eth3
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGES_COMPUTE=br-eth0,br-eth1,br-eth2,br-eth3
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_EXTERNAL_PHYSNET=physnet0,physnet1,physnet2,physnet3
```

Pls advise if this config is good for the requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it works as follows:-

```
1. create new ovs bridge for each ports
2. mapping ovs bridge
3. restart neutron
4. create new provider network
```

Thank you.